# Is this a standard power connector? (from Victron Energy 12V battery charger)

Tags: power, connector, 12v

I am trying to find out whether I can buy this connector.  I've browsed Victron Energy's manuals/specs and can find no mention of the connector name.

[Spec sheet PDF](https://www.victronenergy.com/upload/documents/Folder-A5-Blue-Smart-IP65-Charger-120V_EN_web.pdf)

Note that one of the corners of the male plug prongs is squared off.

[image: Plug]

Comment: Could be custom to them.

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: I have several 12V batteries I have DIY'd and would like a clean charging cable to switch between them (and not using alligator clips or eyelets)

Comment: looks like the company sells them already connected to the appropriate cables ... just cut off un-needed ends ... of course, if they go out of business, and you need more connectors .........

Comment: These are probably custom-made wire assemblies.  The only source is likely Victron Energy.  If they won't sell the cables at a decent price, only option may be to cut the ends off and use new standard connectors.  Shame, they look nice; locking too.

Comment: Just use Anderson PowerPole.  You realize the very PDF you linked advertises these connectors as "for sale as accessories".

Answer (score -1):

Those will likely be custom from Unobtanium Connector Corp.(But you can ask Auk to find if you agree to a $500 MOQ)

https://www.ebay.ca/itm/2-Pin-Molded-Connector-10-Gauge-PigTail-10AWG-Wire-Male-Female/123401604479

These are more common
[image]

Why don’t you just buy them from Vitron?